# Facebook API - Cannot find the URL for

Tags: facebook

I cannot find the link back to the page where my developer settings are! The page with my app secret and redirect URLs etc. etc. I've gone round and around developers.facebook.com for 30 mins.

I'm starting to consider that I didn't actually setup an 'app' on Facebook (I did for Twitter, so maybe I have false memories), but the steps on the tutorial to create a new app don't work either.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#create-app

When it says 'Go to Developer App' I hit that link and it just takes me to my corporate facebook page.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

They have to be here:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

If you cant see it on the left side you do not have any facebook apps :)

Comment: Thanks - I have the new look which mentions no apps, so I assume I didn't set it up, so can you help me find the 'Create New App' button?

Comment: If you can not find the "Create New App" on that page, I think you should either get glasses or maybe computers is not just you! :P

Comment: Ha! I've been doubting my sanity recently but now I'm guessing that Facebook has messed up in its revamp.

Comment: Right, I'm not the only one with this issue. I think its because I created the fan page without having an administrator FB account.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps